# rails generators dynamic output in the generated config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am building a gem and I would like to make a generator for it, I have a code that looks like that :

```
module MagicId
    module Generators
        class ConfigGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
            source_root(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
            def copy_initializer
                copy_file 'config.rb', 'config/initializers/magic_id.rb'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

What it does is copying a config.rb file to the `config/initializers` of rails app, is there a way to make the code of config.rb generated dynamically when I run the generator ?

Answer (score 2):

On the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) for generators, there are 5 methods listed that may be of interest to you.

#### create_file

> ```
> class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
>   def create_initializer_file
>     create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", "# Add initialization content here"
>   end
> end
> ```

This one is actually from [Thor](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/erikhuda/thor/master/Thor/Actions#create_file-instance_method), the second parameter is the contents of the file, or you can give it a block with the return value being used as the contents

> ```
> create_file "lib/fun_party.rb" do
>   hostname = ask("What is the virtual hostname I should use?")
>   "vhost.name = #{hostname}"
> end
>
> create_file "config/apache.conf", "your apache config"
> ```

#### inject_into_file

Puts code at a pre-determined position in your file. ([guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#inject-into-file))

> ```
> inject_into_file 'name_of_file.rb', after: "#The code goes below this line. Don't forget the Line break at the end\n" do <<-'RUBY'
>   puts "Hello World"
> RUBY
> end
> ```

#### gsub_file

Essentially the same as above, except gsubs the position instead of adding a line after it. ([guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#gsub-file))

> ```
> gsub_file 'name_of_file.rb', 'method.to_be_replaced', 'method.the_replacing_code'
> ```

#### append_file/prepend_file

Add to the beginning and add of the file, these both come from the [Thor documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/erikhuda/thor/master/Thor/Actions.html)

> ```
> append_to_file 'config/environments/test.rb', 'config.gem "rspec"'
> prepend_to_file 'config/environments/test.rb', 'config.gem "rspec"'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this

#### in gem code `lib/generators/magic_id_generator.rb`

```
module MagicId
  module Generators
    class ConfigGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      source_root(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))

      argument :name,
               type: :string,
               required: true,
               banner: 'Argument name'

      def copy_config_file
        template 'magic_id.rb.erb', 'config/initializers/magic_id.rb'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### in gem code `lib/generators/templates/magid_id.rb.erb`

```
<%= "MagicId.config do |stuff|" %>
<%= "  stuff.name = :#{name}" %>
<%= "end" %>
```

then `$ rails g magic_id:config is_magic` should produce:

#### in Rails app code `config/initializers/magic_id.rb`

```
MagicId.config do |stuff|
  stuff.name = :is_magic
end
```